# NLE - How to separate and export shots on a video clip

Tags: rendering, video

I have a short film and I want to separate each shot into a separate video file. I've already cut the long string into each shot and named them accordingly.

Is there a way to render and export each shot automatically? Or the only way to go about it is set the starting and ending frame for each shot, press render and repeat it for as many shots I have?

Comment: You can do this via a Python script.